# Relation many-to-many with attributes : how?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

Excuse me for my poor english in advance as it is not my mother tongue.
Like in this example:
http://www.xylax.net/hibernate/manytomany.html


But i have in the table foo-bar 2 attributes which are not part of the primary or foreign keys.: one boolean(A) & one string(B).
I know how to map it without attributes but not in this case. 

I have not found an answer in the documentation.

I need to know please how to map it & what kind of collection i have to declare in my class Foo.

Thanks in advance for your answer. 

I really appreciate the time given by you.

Comment: Could you post your answer to help other users potentially looking for the same solution?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will need to create a third class to hold these attributes

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the  [I have a many-to-many association between two tables, but the association table has some extra columns (apart from the foreign keys). What kind of mapping should I use?](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateFAQ-TipsAndTricks#I_have_a_manytomany_association_between_two_tables_but_the_association_table_has_some_extra_columns_apart_from_the_foreign_keys_What_kind_of_mapping_should_I_use) entry of the Hibernate Users FAQ:

> Use a composite-element to model the
>   association table. For example, given
>   the following association table:
>
> ```
> create table relationship ( 
>     fk_of_foo bigint not null, 
>     fk_of_bar bigint not null, 
>     multiplicity smallint, 
>     created date )
> ```
>
> you could use this collection mapping
>   (inside the mapping for class Foo):
>
> ```
> <set name="relationship">
>     <key column="fk_of_foo"/>
>     <composite-element class="Relationship">
>         <property name="multiplicity" type="short" not-null="true"/>
>         <property name="created" type="date" not-null="true"/>
>         <many-to-one name="bar" class="Bar" not-null="true"/>
>     </composite-element>
> </set>
> ```
>
> You may also use an `<idbag>` with a
>   surrogate key column for the
>   collection table. This would allow you
>   to have nullable columns.
>
> An alternative approach is to simply
>   map the association table as a normal
>   entity class with two bidirectional
>   one-to-many associations.